# Transparent background with body::after limited by the screen size

Tags: html, css

I've been using that code on my body, to get a full background with some mi-transparent white background on it :

```
body { 
      background: url('../images/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    padding-top: 50px; 
}

body::after {
  content: "";
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

The problem is that the white background doesn't go lower than the screen size [as you can see here](http://prntscr.com/91y45c). Any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: Please, post your completed code instead of image.

Comment: that just depends on the size of the body. how long do you want the background to be? longer that the content but still empty? btw someone spelled "sweaty" wrong

Comment: Have you tried `position: fixed` instead of `absolute`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `body::after` isn't fixed, change the css like this :

```
body::after {
  content: "";
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ugh4b93g/) with a black background

Comment: Absolutely perfect. I wonder why I didn't think about it before. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a ::before or ::after pseudo element, you can use **[css multple backgrounds](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)**.

1. Generate the base64 from this site: http://px64.net/
2. Apply the background to the body element.

```css
#foo {

  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  visibility: visible;

}

#foo {
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNgYPhfDwACggF/yWU3jgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) repeat, url(http://www.openkorat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/extra-bg-green.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: auto, cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `::after` element `position: fixed`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4kochj18/)

```css
body { 
      background: url('../images/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

body::after {
  content: "";
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}

div {
    height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div>div</div>
```